# How do I distinguish between iOS apps and macOS apps on my Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, applications, apple-silicon

I have a new M1 Mac Mini running Ventura. I downloaded a few of my iPad apps to see them work, and they now appear on the Applications folder and in the launchpad.

The question is how can I distinguish between iOS apps and other macOS apps?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, **all & only** iPhone/iPad apps have a "Touch Alternatives" option in their **Settings** or **Preferences** (can be opened with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>).

You can also always pull up the app on the App Store and "Open" from there under either "Mac Apps" or "iPhone & iPad Apps."

Note: I am currently on Ventura (macOS 13.0.1).